# How to fix validation errors Response in Netcore 2.2 Web API

Tags: asp.net-core-2.2

I'm handling asp.netcore-2.2 errors but I'm still getting ErrorMessage details from Response

I have a login and register methods with a required username, password and a required password length for registration between 8 and 4 characters the problem is that I get the error messages expected or handled for the login method and I get validation error when I register with empty username and password.

I added this code in ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions:

```
options.SuppressModelStateInvalidFilter = true;
```

and this I tried this option too:

```
options.SuppressUseValidationProblemDetailsForInvalidModelStateResponses = true;
```

but it doesn't work.

This is my Register DTO:

```
using System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations;

namespace DatingApp.Api.Dtos
{
    public class UserForRegisterDto
    {
        [Required]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [StringLength(8, MinimumLength= 4, ErrorMessage= "password between 4 and 8 charracters")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
}
```

I expected this error message:

> "password between 4 and 8 charracters"

but I get this before I change `ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions`:

> "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
>   "status": 400,
>   "traceId": "0HLJIO56EGJEV:00000001"

and a full table with error detail if I use `ConfigureApiBehaviorOptions`.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public class UserForRegisterDto
    {
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "username is required")]
        public string Username { get; set; }
        [Required(ErrorMessage = "password is required")]
        [StringLength(8, MinimumLength= 4, ErrorMessage= "password between 4 and 8 charracters")]
        public string Password { get; set; }
    }
```

i just add error message for required fields .

Comment: Annotations do not make "One or more validation errors occurred." go away. However, the response have errors field as given below

{
    "errors": {
        "Username": [
            "username is required"
        ]},
    "title": "One or more validation errors occurred.",
    "status": 400,
    "traceId": "0HM4INHKS81G6:00000001"
}